# JavaScript: Array created by getElementsByTagName() won't return length of its elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbytagname

I have an array created by `getElementsByTagName()` method and I don't understand why I get `undefined` when I ask for its elements length.

In the code the array in question is called `b`, there's also the array called  `theArray` which is used as an example of the behavior I would expect from the array `b`.

```js
var str = document.getElementById("str");
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

b[0].style.color = "red";
b[1].style.color = "yellow";
b[2].style.color = "green";
 
var theArray = ["Goodbye", "World"]; 

h1[0].innerHTML = b[0].length;
h2[0].innerHTML = theArray[0].length;
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2</h2>

<span id="str">He is <b>likely</b> to be <b>called</b> up for Thursday's <b>match</b> against Italy.</span>
```

**Update:**
What I don't understand is what is the real difference between the array `b` and the `theArray` and why they behave differently. I think, I see what @jens meant by calling them the two different things, that is, one is pure JavaScript the other is generated out of HTML element, but I still don't understand why they behave differently. I mean, at the end they both are just arrays that hold values, aren't they? Could someone please elaborate a little bit more on it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. They both are not the same.**

`var theArray = ["Goodbye", "World"];` this what we call a real array whereas

`var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b");`
 here b is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)  which is again almost same as array with some extra functionality.

[image]

BUT the individual elements contained in the HTMLCollection aren't simple strings that you can call string functions or methods on but rather objects more specifically  [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

[image]

You can say this is analogues to java ; in java you can find length of an array using `length` property and for strings you can use `length()` method but you can't do that on class objects like `employee.length;` (unless you have implemented that function in the class yourself).This is exactly similar to `b[0].length;` you were doing

Now you can guess what you need to do to fix this.You need to get the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property which holds a *string representation of the contents of an html tag*. You can call that on the HTMLElement object of that tag( which is obj representation of that tag , sorta "handle" to the tag)

```js
var str = document.getElementById("str");
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

b[0].style.color = "red";
b[1].style.color = "yellow";
b[2].style.color = "green";
 
var theArray = ["Goodbye", "World"]; 

h1[0].innerHTML = b[0].innerHTML.length;
h2[0].innerHTML = theArray[0].length;
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2</h2>

<span id="str">He is <b>likely</b> to be <b>called</b> up for Thursday's <b>match</b> against Italy.</span>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the length of two different things. In the case of `b[0].length` you are trying to get the length of an HTML Element. `b.length` would give you 3 because 3 elements were matched. With `theArray[0].length` you are getting the length of a string which works.

Comment: I know that `b.length` gives 3, which is expected, thank you. What I don't understand is what is the real difference between the array `b` and the `theArray` and why they behave differently. I think, I see what you meant by calling them the two different things, that is, one is pure JavaScript the other is generated out of HTML element, but I still don't understand why they behave differently. I mean, at the end they both are just arrays that hold values, aren't they? Could you please elaborate a little bit more on it? Thank you!

Comment: b is an HTMLCollection so you can get the length of that. b[0] is the first element matched in the collection, it is an HTMLElement, which doesn't have a length. theArray is a vanilla JS array it also has a length, so do both of the strings that are elements of theArray.

Answer (score 1):

any `document.getSomethingBySomething` returns an **object**, which is **different from an array**. An object can be written by `{ "property" : "value", "next property" : "next value" }`, and can be written or read by `object.property`, `object["property"]`, `object["property"] = value`, or `object.property = value`.

Mean while, an array is written or read by `array[index] = value`, or `array[index]`. **The major difference** between objects and arrays is that **arrays are referenced with numbers**, while **objects are referenced by property names** (strings). To get the **length of an object** simply use `object.keys(b).length`, since `object.keys` returns all the property names of an object in  an array format, which supports `.length`.

Anything you could ever wanna know is here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: It's funny you asked this cause I actually had the same problem

Comment: try formatting the *cody* parts of your post, it becomes a lot more readable and increases chances of anyone reading it at all, ;)